# How to use env variables in yaml-cpp with C++

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

config.yaml:

```
home: "$HOME"
```

main.cpp:

```
int main() {
YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("config.yaml");
const std::string home = config["home"].asstd::string();
std::cout << home << std::endl;
}
```

How can I get the value of env variable $HOME in my C++ code instead of `$HOME`?

Comment: I wonder if this question isn't really related to yaml.  As I read this, it seems to be asking how to get an environment variable from a string that holds the variable's name.

Comment: This is nothing YAML does for you. You need to walk the loaded graph and replace every scalar value starting with `$` with the value of the corresponding env variable yourself.